# Перемещение камеры вслед за курсором

Tags: c++, математика, opengl, vulkan, glm

Пишу приложение на Vulkan, но я читал статьи и по Vulkan и по OpenGL. Принцип одинаков. Я хочу сделать перемещение камеры как в инструментах для работы с 3D графикой. Ниже пример:

[image: Cinema 4d]

Вот тут зажимается сочетание клавиш (alt + колёсико мыши) и камера движется за курсором. Я вот не понимаю как мне сделать также. Я сначала попробовал делать через эдакую переменную чувствительности. Но при одном окне подобранная переменная работает более менее нормально. Делаешь окно во весь экран, меняется аспект и уже получается слишком быстро или слишком медленно. Можно конечно, подобрать и переумножать с учётом аспекта, но если ещё учесть что у разных пользователей может быть разная чувствительность мыши, то  всё сломается. Далее я попробовал делать через получение мировых координат. Но у меня оно работает только если камера смотрит ровно прямо, а под углом уже не работает. Потом до меня дошло что возможно я камеру передвигаю неправильно, ведь она может находиться в области от `[-n, -k]`. Ведь я изменяю не значение x, а изменяю сразу вектор. Нужно изменять сразу вектор т.к. если камера будет под углом и как мне нужно нацеленной, то с каждым перемещением нужно править все 3 оси.

Покажу что пока есть:

Действия при удержании сочетания клавиш

```cpp
void ShortcutMouseEvent::onPressMoveCamera()
{
    double xpos, ypos; /// инициализация текущей позиции курсора
    glfwGetCursorPos(sMouseEvent->pWindow, &xpos, &ypos); /// sMouseEvent - контейнер где хранятся данные при работе с мышью
    if (!sMouseEvent->isAllocated) { /// Если данные ещё неизвестны
        sMouseEvent->pInit = new glm::vec2 { xpos, ypos };
        sMouseEvent->pLast = new glm::vec2 { xpos, ypos };
        sMouseEvent->isAllocated = true;
    } else {
        float xoffset = sMouseEvent->pLast->x - xpos; /// Тут должно быть понятно
        float yoffset = sMouseEvent->pLast->y - ypos;
        float yaw = sMouseEvent->pCamera->object.transform.rotation.y; /// Фактически это таже реализация что и в OpenGL Tutorial
        const glm::vec3 forwardDir { sin(yaw), 0.f, cos(yaw) };
        const glm::vec3 rightDir { forwardDir.z, 0.f, -forwardDir.x };
        const glm::vec3 upDir { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
        glm::vec3 moveDir { 0.0f };
        moveDir -= rightDir; /// Тут мы говорим что нужно перемещать только в сторону x (пока пытаюсь заставить работать на одной оси)
        auto world = sMouseEvent->screenToWorldSpace(sMouseEvent->pWindow, sMouseEvent->pCamera, xpos, ypos); // Получение мировых координат
        sMouseEvent->pCamera->object.transform.position += 0.0066f * world.x * xoffset * glm::normalize(moveDir); /// Так оно работает при окне 800x600 (аспект 1.3333 если не ошибаюсь)
        sMouseEvent->pLast->x = xpos;
        sMouseEvent->pLast->y = ypos;
    }
}
```

Функция получения мировых координат:

```cpp
glm::vec4 ShortcutMouseEvent::screenToWorldSpace(GLFWwindow* window, Camera* pCamera, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    int width, height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
    double xNdc = (2.0 * xpos / width) - 1;
    double yNdc = (2.0 * ypos / height) - 1;
    glm::mat4 proj = pCamera->getProjection();
    glm::mat4 view = pCamera->getView();
    glm::mat4 viewProjectionInverse = glm::inverse(proj * view);
    glm::vec4 worldAffine { -xNdc, -yNdc, -pCamera->object.transform.position.z, -pCamera->object.transform.position.z };
    return worldAffine * viewProjectionInverse;
}
```

На последней функции думаю комментарии излишни. Вроде и так ясно. Я пробовал и без оффсета, и перемножать/делить w компонента для преобразования из аффинного пространства. Ничего не получается.

Просьба помочь. Я только начинаю изучать программирование графики и мне определенно не хватает опыта.

UPD: Я тут перечитал что написал. Кстати по поводу разной чувствительности мыши помомне я был неправ. И она не будет на что-то влиять в коде. Т.к. всё на что она будет влиять - это на оффсет. Т.е. чем быстрее будет двигаться мышка, тем и больше будет оффсет.
Я пробовал:

```cpp
((width / height) / 250.0f) * xoffset * glm::normalize(moveDir);
```

```cpp
0.0066f * (width/height) * xoffset * glm::normalize(moveDir);
```

Здесь то же самое. При маленьком окошке норм. При окне на весь экран результат другой.

UPD: Я получил комментарий от @Laukhin Andrey. Нужно перемножать радиус до цели, высоту и интенсивность перемещения (`panFactor`) По коду вроде всё понятно. В примере всё работает. А у меня почему-то подбираешь `panFactor` и в стандартном окне всё нормально. Увеличиваешь/уменьшаешь окно и уже анимация слишком быстрая. Не пойму что я делаю нет так.
Я вообще подозреваю что дело в радиусе. Ну поскольку я знаю расстояние камеры, то зная углы можно поидее рассчитать как:

```cpp
float radius = (pos.z * glm::sin(rot.x)) / glm::tan(rot.x);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также пробовал и перевести в OpenGL где построение матрицы вида происходит через вектора. (Я используя углы эйлера где в качестве входных данных приходит позиция и вращения) Результат тот же. Плюс в обоих случаях ещё почему то анимация -x происходит быстрее +x.

Формирование матрицы вида:

```cpp
  const float c3 = glm::cos(rotation.z);
  const float s3 = glm::sin(rotation.z);
  const float c2 = glm::cos(rotation.x);
  const float s2 = glm::sin(rotation.x);
  const float c1 = glm::cos(rotation.y);
  const float s1 = glm::sin(rotation.y);
  const glm::vec3 u{(c1 * c3 + s1 * s2 * s3), (c2 * s3), (c1 * s2 * s3 - c3 * s1)};
  const glm::vec3 v{(c3 * s1 * s2 - c1 * s3), (c2 * c3), (c1 * c3 * s2 + s1 * s3)};
  const glm::vec3 w{(c2 * s1), (-s2), (c1 * c2)};
  mViewMatrix = glm::mat4{1.f};
  mViewMatrix[0][0] = u.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][0] = u.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][0] = u.z;
  mViewMatrix[0][1] = v.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][1] = v.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][1] = v.z;
  mViewMatrix[0][2] = w.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][2] = w.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][2] = w.z;
  mViewMatrix[3][0] = -glm::dot(u, position);
  mViewMatrix[3][1] = -glm::dot(v, position);
  mViewMatrix[3][2] = -glm::dot(w, position);
```

Панирование:

```cpp
        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(sMouseEvent->pWindow, &xpos, &ypos);
        if (!sMouseEvent->isAllocated)
        {
            sMouseEvent->pInit = new glm::vec2{xpos, ypos};
            sMouseEvent->pLast = new glm::vec2{xpos, ypos};
            sMouseEvent->isAllocated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            float dx = xpos - sMouseEvent->pLast->x;
            float dy = ypos - sMouseEvent->pLast->y;
            int width, height;
            glfwGetWindowSize(sMouseEvent->pWindow, &width, &height);

            if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
            {
                float yaw = sMouseEvent->pCamera->object.transform.rotation.y;
                const glm::vec3 forwardDir{sin(yaw), 0.f, cos(yaw)};
                glm::vec3 rightDir{forwardDir.z, 0.f, -forwardDir.x};
                glm::vec3 upDir = glm::cross(forwardDir, rightDir);

                glm::vec3 &pos = sMouseEvent->pCamera->object.transform.position;
                glm::vec3 &rot = sMouseEvent->pCamera->object.transform.rotation;
                float radius = (pos.z * glm::sin(yaw)) / glm::tan(yaw);
                const float panFactor = 0.01f;
                dx *= panFactor;
                dy *= panFactor;

                dx *= radius / 3;
                dy *= radius / 3;

                dx *= 1000.0f / height;
                dy *= 1000.0f / height;
                glm::vec3 ov = glm::normalize(rightDir) * dx + glm::normalize(upDir) * dy;

                pos += ov;
            }
            sMouseEvent->pLast->x = xpos;
            sMouseEvent->pLast->y = ypos;
        }
```

Попытка сделать тоже самое через OpenGL:

```cpp
            float dx = xpos - lastX;
            float dy = lastY - ypos;
            const float panFactor = 0.002f;
            const float radius = 15.0f;
            int width, height;
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);

            dx *= panFactor;
            dy *= panFactor;

            dx *= radius / 3;
            dy *= radius / 3;

            dx *= 1000 / height;
            dy *= 1000 / height;

            glm::vec3 cameraRight = glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraUp, cameraFront));

            glm::vec3 ov = glm::normalize(cameraRight) * dx + glm::normalize(cameraUp) * -dy;

            cameraPos += ov;
```

Full screen:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стандартное окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Построение матрицы проекции:

```cpp
  assert(glm::abs(aspect - FLT_EPSILON) > 0.0f);
  const float tanHalfFovy = tan(fov.mFovV / 2.f);
  mProjectionMatrix = glm::mat4{0.0f};
  mProjectionMatrix[0][0] = 1.f / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);
  mProjectionMatrix[1][1] = 1.f / (tanHalfFovy);
  mProjectionMatrix[2][2] = far / (far - near);
  mProjectionMatrix[2][3] = 1.f;
  mProjectionMatrix[3][2] = -(far * near) / (far - near);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140708/discussion-on-question-by-wusiki-jeronii-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью stackoverflow я разобрался. У меня было много чего неправильно. Понимание как работает навигация, построение матриц, и т.д. Обо всём по порядку.
Как я писал в дискуссии код построения матриц я брал с туториалов. Матрица проекции была инверсивной. Под инверсивную матрицу подстраивалась и инверсивная матрица вида. В результате ничего не получалось даже имея примеры потому что расчёты в случае изменения окна не сходились. А писать вообще матрицы я начал потому что так было в уроках. Тогда (при инверсивном подходе) я пробовал заменить на `glm::perspectiveLH`. Но при неправильном подходе оно и не работало правильно. При текущем коде можно спокойно заменить на функции из библиотеки `glm`.
Я переписал:

Матрица проекции

```cpp
void Camera::setPerspectiveProjection(float aspect, float near, float far)
{
  assert(glm::abs(aspect - FLT_EPSILON) > 0.0f);
  const float tanHalfFovy = tan(fov.mFovV / 2.f);
  mProjectionMatrix = glm::mat4{0.0f};
  mProjectionMatrix[0][0] = 1.f / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);
  mProjectionMatrix[1][1] = 1.f / tanHalfFovy;
  mProjectionMatrix[2][2] = -((far + near) / (far - near));
  mProjectionMatrix[2][3] = -1.f;
  mProjectionMatrix[3][2] = -((2.0f * far * near) / (far - near));
}
```

Матрица вида:

```
void Camera::setViewYXZ(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 rotation)
{
  const float c3 = glm::cos(rotation.z);
  const float s3 = glm::sin(rotation.z);
  const float c2 = glm::cos(rotation.x);
  const float s2 = glm::sin(rotation.x);
  const float c1 = glm::cos(rotation.y);
  const float s1 = glm::sin(rotation.y);
  const glm::vec3 u{(c1 * c3 + s1 * s2 * s3), (c2 * s3), (c1 * s2 * s3 - c3 * s1)};
  const glm::vec3 v{(c3 * s1 * s2 - c1 * s3), (c2 * c3), (c1 * c3 * s2 + s1 * s3)};
  const glm::vec3 w{(c2 * s1), (-s2), (c1 * c2)};
  mViewMatrix = glm::mat4{1.f};
  mViewMatrix[0][0] = u.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][0] = u.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][0] = -u.z;
  mViewMatrix[0][1] = v.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][1] = v.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][1] = -v.z;
  mViewMatrix[0][2] = w.x;
  mViewMatrix[1][2] = w.y;
  mViewMatrix[2][2] = -w.z;
  mViewMatrix[3][0] = glm::dot(u, position);
  mViewMatrix[3][1] = glm::dot(v, position);
  mViewMatrix[3][2] = glm::dot(w, position);
}
```

Второй момент - я воспринимал камеру как объект с векторам, но для решения задачи с навигацией лучше всего абстрагироваться сферой. Я покажу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно представить что есть виртуальная сфера, а камера - это точка на этой сфере. И тогда понятно как перемещается, вращается и зумируется камера.

Код функции понамирования:

```cpp
    void ShortcutMouseEvent::onPressPanCamera()
    {
        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(sMouseEvent->pWindow, &xpos, &ypos);
        if (!sMouseEvent->isAllocated)
        {
            allocateRes();
            return;
        }
        float dx = xpos - sMouseEvent->pLast->x;
        float dy = ypos - sMouseEvent->pLast->y;
        if (sMouseEvent->isHold)
        {
            float yaw = sMouseEvent->pCamera->transform.rotation.y;
            const glm::vec3 forwardDir{sin(yaw), 0.f, cos(yaw)};
            glm::vec3 rightDir{forwardDir.z, 0.f, -forwardDir.x};
            glm::vec3 upDir = glm::cross(forwardDir, rightDir);

            const float panFactor = 1.f;
            dx *= panFactor;
            dy *= panFactor;

            const float targetDisance = sMouseEvent->pCamera->lengthSphereSpace *
                                        glm::tan(sMouseEvent->pCamera->fov.mFovV / 2.0f);
            dx *= targetDisance;
            dy *= targetDisance;

            dx *= 2.0f / sMouseEvent->dimensions.x;
            dy *= 2.0f / sMouseEvent->dimensions.y;
            glm::vec3 ov = glm::normalize(rightDir) * dx + glm::normalize(upDir) * dy;

            sMouseEvent->pCamera->transform.position += ov;
        }
        else if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
            isHold = true;
        sMouseEvent->pLast->x = xpos;
        sMouseEvent->pLast->y = ypos;
    }

    void ShortcutMouseEvent::onReleasePanCamera()
    {
        dealocateRes();
    }
```

И чтобы прояснить код:

- `panFactor` - чувствительность панамирования
- `lengthSphereSpace` - это радиус сферы. Высчитывается как [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), но поскольку у меня таргет смотрит всегда в сторону `0, 0, 0`, то формула `sqrt(pos.x * pos.x + pos.y * pos.y + pos.z * pos.z)`. Он также должен быть неизменяемым во время паномирования.
- `mFovV` - это вертикальный fov. Он должен быть неизменяемым во время паномирования. К примеру, у меня инициализация fov идёт через ширину сенсора и фокусное расстояние. И при определении вертикального fov используется аспект, а он может быть различным при изменении пропорций окна. У меня есть некая виртуальная камера с заданными высотой и шириной и fov просчитывается исходя из этих настроек.

Всё остальное должно быть понятно.